# Rendering API data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements

I am trying to make an API call and conditionally render data to the page. If it meets a certain criteria (date in this case), I want to display it, otherwise I don't want it to show up on the page. However, when I type in `null` I still get 4 items logging as "null" in my console (I only want the 'display to page' item to show up). I have followed this approach in previous projects and it has worked...anyone know what might be happening here? Any insights would be appreciated, thanks!

```
useEffect(() => {
axios({
  method: "get",
  url: `http://dataservice.accuweather.com/forecasts/v1/daily/5day/${userInput}`,
  params: {
    apikey: "<API_key>",
  },
})
  .then((response) => {
    setWeatherData(
      response.data.DailyForecasts.map((item) => {
        console.log(
          item.Date === "2022-05-31T07:00:00-04:00"
            ? "display to page"
            : null
        );
      })
    );
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
  }, [userInput]);
```

When mapping over it in the jsx, I did this:

```
 <section className="wrapper weatherContainer">
   {weatherData.map((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    return (
      <div className="topContainer">
       
        {/* if date matches today's date, display on top container, otherwise don't display anything */}
        {
          data.Date === "2022-05-31T07:00:00-04:00" ? (
            <div className="topContainer">
              <h1>Today</h1>
              <p>
                <img
                  src={require(`../../assets/${data.Day.Icon}.png`)}
                  alt={data.Day.IconPhrase}
                />
                {toCelcius(data.Temperature.Maximum.Value).toFixed(0)}&#176;
              </p>
              <p>{data.Day.IconPhrase}</p>
            </div>
          ) : null
        }
      </div>
    );
  })}
</section>
```

Comment: Can you share the output of `console.log(response)` ?

Comment: it's a nested object https://ibb.co/X7ByMDf

Comment: Looks like the `response.data.DailyForecasts` does not have an item that matches the specific date. Can you expand and share the data inside `DailyForecasts` ?

Comment: The date is located inside DailyForecasts https://ibb.co/5TrrCvs
I am able to retrieve the first date, however for the remaining dates it renders an empty div however I was hoping the null in the else statement would prevent it from showing up altogether

Comment: added an answer.. see if it works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empty `<div>`s show up because the first map function within `<section>` tags return a `<div className="topContainer">` even if the item does not match. Returning the item only if it is matched does the trick.

```
<section className="wrapper weatherContainer">
    {weatherData.map((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    return (
        data.Date === "2022-05-31T07:00:00-04:00" ? (
            <div className="topContainer">
                <h1>Today</h1>
                ... rest of the elements
            </div>
        ) : null
    );
    })}
</section>
```

Comment: Yes, this works! Wow..I was so hung up on the logic that I didn't even realize. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You are not logging properly. Look, in your ternary operator, you say if `true` - log `"display to page"`, else log `null`. To log only elements which are

```
item.Date === "2022-05-31T07:00:00-04:00"
```

You need to do this way

```
if(item.Date === "2022-05-31T07:00:00-04:00") console.log(item)
```

Comment: I cannot use if statements in my jsx though....I am hoping to display this to the page, the console.log is just an example.